# get unmatched records form first table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

**Table1:**

```
+---------------------+
|id  |  name | company|
+---------------------+ 
|1   |  sai  |  abc   |
|2   |  sri  |  xyz   |
|4   |  abx  |  bcd   |
+---------------------+
```

**Table2:**

```
+---------------------------+
| id  |  emp_name |  salary |
+---------------------------+
| 1   |     sai   |   20k   |
| 4   |     abx   |   40k   |
+---------------------------+
```

when both the tables are compared, the unmatched data of `table1` only should come.

**Result:**

```
+----------------------+
|id  | name  | company |
+----------------------+
|2   |  sri  |   xyz   |
+----------------------+
```

**I have tried:**

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 b WHERE a.id = b.id)
```

Comment: The query you posted should work. So with the info posted it is not possible to reproduce the *actual* issue you are facing.

Comment: Your query is correct for this requirement. this will produce expected result same as u expect. whats problem ?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Is correct, your current query [appears to be working](http://rextester.com/OBYO97075).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester